# SQL: Find first occurrence of any character except the one specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

All,

Using SSMS v17.2

Long story short I have 15 columns in a table, each record in the table has a different number of columns filled out, the rest are null. I then concatenate the columns with a comma delimiter. Problem is the fields which are null also get concatenated leaving me with trailing commas.

```
ARNP,ACLS Provider,BLS Provider CPR,,,,,,,,,,,,
COC,CPC,CRC,CPC-1,,,,,,,,,,,
CISSP,CCNA Security,Network +,,,,,,,,,,,,
Leadership (All levels),Education (Grades K-12),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

As you can see the very last character before the trailing commas can be either alpha numeric or special characters. I need help removing these training commas up to the first character that is not a comma such as the below.

```
ARNP,ACLS Provider,BLS Provider CPR
COC,CPC,CRC,CPC-1
CISSP,CCNA Security,Network +
Leadership (All levels),Education (Grades K-12)
```

Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: And what SQL implementation are you using? Does it have `CONCAT_WS`? SSMS is just the client. What version of (presumably) SQL Server are you connecting to?

Comment: Looks like your source table is not at all normalised BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the correct data after concatenation:

```
SELECT LEFT(@MyData, charindex(',,', @Mydata) - 1)
```

This prevents the trailing commas from being concatenated:

```
SELECT Col1 + ',' + IsNull(Col2 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col3 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col4 + ',', '') + 
    IsNull(Col5 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col6 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col7 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col8 + ',', '') +
    IsNull(Col9 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col10 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col11 + ',', '') + 
    IsNull(Col12 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col13 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col14 + ',', '') + IsNull(Col15, '')
```

Actually, the above only works if concatenating a null returns a null. If this line:

```
SELECT 'xxx' + NULL
```

returns

```
xxx
```

then my second suggestion does not work

Comment: The double comma solution is genius. so simple. Thank you.